# What is the source of these reddish stains on my drywall?

Tags: drywall, paint, staining

Some of my painted interior walls have reddish spots and streaks appearing.  The stain appears to be on top of the paint and not the underlying material.  Age of the paint and house is about 20 years.

[image: stains]

Comment: Somebody likes to smack flies?  Use a damp cloth/paper and see if they wipe off.

Comment: Call C.S.I.   Looks like blood splatter.

Comment: Do you have pets that like to shake stuff off their paws or ears?  Or sneeze?  Or ... how shall I put it... fart+?

Comment: It's a house used by intravenous drug users, just like the one that appeared on Reddit recently.